# select distinct along with other rows outer / join?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table similar to

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id    type    report_id    state    ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1     dc      122          pending  ║
║ 2     dc      123          pending  ║
║ 3     dc      123          approved ║
║ 4     dc      123          pending  ║
║ 5     dc      123          approved ║
║ 6     bb      123          pending  ║
║ 7     dc      123          pending  ║
║ 8     dc      124          pending  ║
║ 9     dc      125          pending  ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I am trying to fetch the last report_id by type where state is pending
so results I would want are

```
122 (id 1 -- dc)
123 (id 6 -- bb)
123 (id 7 -- dc)
124 (id 8 -- dc)
125 (id 9 -- dc)
```

Right now I am fetching all, then running 3 loops on the array... I know there is a way to either `join` or perform an `outer` query to get it without the loops, any input on how i would word it?

I ran a query on a test database (15 records) and it worked there, but hangs on the live database (40k records)

```
SELECT report_id, type, state
FROM histories
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM histories
  GROUP BY report_id
)
AND state <> 'approved'
```

For this, the sub-query executes fine and gives me proper results, the main query will give me results if I extract the sub-query, but combine them and it hangs...
Tested on ta SQL (not MySQL) database on a local machine with a limited data-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was this

take the sub-query and run it

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM histories
GROUP BY report_id
... store as $id_array
```

then take the result and store it as CSV

```
$id_csv = implode(', ' $id_array);
```

then run my primary query

```
SELECT report_id, type, state
FROM histories
WHERE id IN ($id_csv)
AND state <> 'approved'
```

Not sure why it made a difference separating it, but it did the job (query takes about 3 seconds to run, I wish it were faster)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a `group by` with a filter:

```
select report_id, type, max(id)
from table t
where state = 'pending'
group by report_id, type;
```

Comment: updated my question with a query that should, but doesnt work

Comment: @Kender . . . Your query cannot do what you want.  It would return at most one row per `report_id`, but your sample data has two rows for 123.

Comment: I was using that query, looped for each type `dc` and `bb` to get my last of each type

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT report_id, MAX(id), type
FROM table_name
WHERE state = 'pending'
GROUP BY report_id, type
ORDER BY report_id
```

where table_name is your tables name. It is difficult to tell what you want from the results in your question.

Comment: updated my question with a query that should, but doesnt work